# Laravel - Mostrar información que no se encuentra en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql

Estoy intentando traer información que no se encuentra en otra tabla:

```
----------------------
   Notificaciones
----------------------
id
mensaje


----------------------
 Noti_leidas
----------------------
id_notificacion
id_usuario
```

Como podria hacer una consulta que solo me muestre los datos que no se encuentre en la tabla `noti_leidas`.

Actualmente tengo:

```
$tareas = DB::table('notificaciones')
                ->leftJoin('Noti_leidas','notificaciones.id','=','Noti_leidas.tarea_id')
                ->get();
```

pero no me funciona, me muestra información a la inversa y hace falta pasarle el `id de usuario`

Comment: ¿asumo que las dos tablas están relacionadas y dichas relaciones están definidas en los modelos?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recoger los valores (notificaciones_id) que quieres en un array (llamemoslo $tu_array) de la tabla noti_leidas y hacer una consulta en notificaciones con el método "whereNotIn":

```
DB::table('notificaciones')->select(...)->whereNotIn('id',$tu_array)->get();
```

No obstante, viendo esto, te hago una pregunta:

¿la tabla noti_leidas tiene información "clonada" de la tabla notificaciones? No se el volumen de datos que manejas y por lo tanto, si es adecuado el tener dos tablas (ni tampoco si la pregunta que te he hecho tiene respuesta afirmativa), pero en caso de que sea así, (solo te pregunto), ¿no sería mejor que añadieses un campo a la tabla "notificaciones" que te diga si la notificación ha sido leida?

leida: TINYINT

Si es el caso, conseguirias quitarte una tabla de encima, no manejar información duplicada, olvidarte de tener que andar siempre replicando/borrando/actualizando, etc...información duplicada e incluso llegar a evitarte problemas de integridad de datos, etc..

Comment: Si lleva información clonada solo de id_notificacion, no puedo agregar una columna debido a que va para multiples usuarios.

Comment: @DoubleM ok. sólo trataba de ayudar en la medida de lo posible :) 
A ver si el codigo te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Se podría hacer en una sola consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
DB::table('notificaciones')->select(...)->whereNotIn('id',DB::table('Noti_leidas')->select('id_notificacion')->get())->get();
```